# Student vs Teacher

Tags: python, django

I am coding a model in Django.

I am using the User model from django.contrib.auth.models

I need to create a teacher entity and student entity.

They are basically the same - they all required username, password, email except for student type = 'student' and type = 'teacher'

How can I represent the Teacher and Student models?

Should I be extending User model for both the teacher and student?
or should I just create one model extending from the User model that just has a different type for student and teacher.

Thanks!

I have

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

class Teacher(Profile):
    salary = models.FloatField()

class Student(Profile)
    grade = models.FloatField()
```

Where User refers to the User model in django.contrib.auth.models

Comment: what about object inheritence?

Comment: what about "Groups" and "Privileges" from django.contrib.auth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with what you have, it's a valid patten: please read this tho: http://charlesleifer.com/blog/django-patterns-model-inheritance/ it's a good read and explains **Model Inheritance** in more detail. Read on multi-table inheritance and abstract models too.